# detecting the change of content of UITextField when the change is not made by the keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ios6

I have a `UIButton` and a `UITextField`,when the button is pressed the textfield's content string will be equal to: `This is a test string`, how can I detect that this text field has changed its contents in this case?

p.s. `UITextField's` delegate methods do not work in such case

**UPDATE:** I want this behavior to be on iOS 6+ devices.

Comment: If the `UIButton` is hooked up to an `IBAction` that changes the `UITextField's` text, the aren't you notified that this happened when the `IBAction` gets called?

Comment: `IBAction`'s work in every `iOS`. To clarify, if you've hooked up a method to you `UIButton` that changes the text of the `UITextField`, then why don't you just call another method at the end of the `UIButton`'s method?

Comment: I just managed to do it in iOS6 via KVO. Check out my answer. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe simple [**key-value observing**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/NSKeyValueObserving) will work?

```
[textField addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"text" options:0 context:nil];

- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"text"] && object == textField) {
        // text has changed
    }
}
```

---

Edit: I just checked it, and it works for me.

Comment: The problem with it is that UIKit is not KVO-compliant

Answer (score 16):

You can add the `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification`:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(textFieldChanged:)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:textField];
```

`textField` (param object) is your UITextField.
`selector` is your method that will be called when this notification was fired.

Comment: it sounds there is a bug in iOS 6, because it doesn't work on iOS6 and works on iOS 5, I will update the question.

Comment: I think Apple changed this behaviour. In this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754948/uitextfieldtextdidchangenotification-doesnt-get-called-on-ios6-ipad3) it's the same problem. I didn't test it under iOS 6.

Comment: This worked for me, while the UITextFieldDelegate method 'textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:' would always fire one character short of the current contents, and the 'addTarget:action:forControlEvents:' approach, whether in code or in IB (Storyboard) would have the action never fire! I would imagine this is a bug (I'm on iOS7.0.2). Thankfully, the notification approach described in @Sebastian's answer, worked perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

You can handle text change within `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event. So when you change text programmaticaly just send this event:

```
textField.text = @"This is a test string";
[textField sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Comment: this is a manual triggering of the event, in a large project this is impractical to send the event with every text change.

Answer (score 4):

The delegate method may actually work for you. You get the text field, the range that will change, and the new string. You can put these together to determine the proposed string.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range        replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSMutableString *proposed = [NSMutableString stringWithString:textField.text];
    [proposed replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    NSLog(@"%@", proposed);
    // Do stuff.
    return YES; // Or NO. Whatever. It's your function.
}
```

Comment: This is one character late.Use notification  https://stackoverflow.com/a/13952247/233333

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty robust solution, but it should work. In your function that is called when you press the button...

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is a test string"];
if(string == textfield.text){
...
}
```

Or, you can us a self scheduler to check if it has changed repeatedly.

Comment: Should not test NSString or any NSObject equality using ==

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Swift3 version of akashivskyy's answer:

```
func startObservingTextView() {
    textView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath:"text", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions(rawValue: 0), context: nil)
}

func stopObservingTextView() {
    textView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "text")
}

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if let textViewObject = object as? UITextView, textViewObject == textView, keyPath == "text" {
        // text has changed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Swift 5.4

Here is a Swift 5.4 version of akashivskyy's answer:

Use [NSKeyValueObservation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/nskeyvalueobserving) key-value observing.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtTextField: UITextField!
    
    private var textObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        textObservation = self.txtTextField.observe(\.text, options: [.new, .old], changeHandler: { (object, value) in
            print("New value is : ", value.newValue)
            print("Old value is : ", value.oldValue)
        })
    }
}
```