# Why is editingChanged not a function in UITextFieldDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

In my project, I needed to toggle a save button whenever the text in 2 of my textFields changed, so I instinctively looked into the methods of `UITextFieldDelegate`, since I was already using it.

I learned that there is no method for doing this, the closest is `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, which does not solve my problem (technically it does, but it's way more complex than it needs to be).

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7850787/1955488) answer, where the edited part says to create an `IBAction` for each textField's `editingChanged`.

In `UITextFieldDelegate`, there are functions for `shouldBegin/didBegin`, and `shouldEnd/didEnd`. Why is there only a function for `shouldChange` and not `didChange`?

Comment: There's easier way for this, [use KVO or notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13952177/detecting-the-change-of-content-of-uitextfield-when-the-change-is-not-made-by-th)

Comment: All I needed to do was drag an IBAction from each textField to the same function. It doesn't get much easier than that